# Using android FFMPEG library for limited video frames

Tags: android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have to show only 10 frames from the video, the below code is bringing all the frames of the video, is there any query set available in FFmpeg for a limited number of frames in android and display in video editing like WhatsApp.
A query in below like this is highly appreciated.

String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};

Comment: Do you want frames 1-10, or 10 frames equally spaced from the complete duration of the video?

Comment: only 10 frames from the complete video.

Comment: Try "Output specific number of equally spaced frames" in duplicate link above.

Comment: can you please mention and write query here

Comment: please write down the query of the FFmpeg command to extract here only 10 frames, I tried your mentioned link but it not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236741/discussion-between-waris-ali-rehmani-and-llogan).

Comment: "not working" is a useless, unhelpful description of the problem. [Edit] your question to show your command and the complete log.